# Spark - Changing memory fraction dynamically

Tags: apache-spark

I have a Spark job which needs a large portion of executor memory in the first half and large portion of user memory in the second half. Is there any way to dynamically change Spark memory fraction during runtime?

Comment: did you check this one http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview

Comment: also what do you mean user memory?

Comment: @Shankar https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/

Answer (score 0):

Short: `spark.*` configuration option cannot be changed on run-time.

Longer: There should be no need to. If you use recent Spark (1.6 or later) memory settings are deprecated. You can set `spark.memory.useLegacyMode` and Spark will do the rest.

Comment: As far as I know, Unified memory management is only applicable to RDD memory i.e. --spark.memory.fraction . There is still no way to share spark.memory.fraction and 1-spark.memory.fraction